# How do I add or edit articles in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, content

Articles (AKA content) are one of the most important parts of a website, but how do I create new articles, or edit existing articles? How does the article editor work, and what are all the buttons in the toolbar for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joomla articles are managed using the Article Manager, in the <kbd>Content</kbd> → <kbd>Article Manager</kbd> menu. Some of the options to manage articles are:

[image: Articles toolbar]

- **New** (see Article editor below)
- **Edit** (select an article and click <kbd>Edit</kbd>, or click the article title directly)
- **Publish/Unpublish** (make selected article(s) visible or invisible to visitors)
- **Featured** (Featured articles are displayed using the Menu Item Type *Featured Articles*.)
- **Archive** (Archived articles are not visible in normal blog view, but can be listed using the Menu Item Type *Archived Articles*.
- **Check In** (Removes the padlock from checked-out items. Read more on [Joomla! Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/What_do_the_locks_mean_and_how_do_you_get_rid_of_them%3F).)
- **Trash** (delete checked article(s). Trashed articles can be viewed and recovered by setting the *status* filter to *Trashed*.)
- **Batch** (displays options for batch processing all selected articles. Useful for changing category, language, tags, menu location and access levels. **No undo button - use with caution**.)

### Choosing article editor

By default, Joomla includes 2 article editors (in addition to *None*):

- TinyMCE ([WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)/[WYSINWYG](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/WYSINWYG) editor - Default)
- CodeMirror (HTML code editor)

Additional editors can be found [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/editors).

The default editor can be set under <kbd>System</kbd> → <kbd>Global Configuration</kbd>, and each user can be assigned a different editor from the user manager. A  <kbd>Toggle Editor</kbd> button is located in the lower right corner , but it only switches between *TinyMCE* and *None*. (A couple of [plugins](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/editor-buttons/9912) are available that allows changing between all available editors from the edit page.)

### Editing articles

The actual content of a single article can be edited by clicking the article title in the article manager, or by selecting an article and clicking the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button. This will open the Article editor.

The default (TinyMCE) editor looks like this:

[image: TinyMCE]

Simply write your content directly into the box, and use the toolbar to add **bold**, *italics*, underline and other formatting to your text. If you're familiar with HTML, press the <kbd>< ></kbd> button to see and edit the article source code.

**Note:** Often it's needed to paste text from Word or other text editors. Keep in mind that they often include CSS styling that will override your website's CSS style, and might break your page layout. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste as pure text, and add any text formatting using TinyMCE.

Comment: Thanks for the **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **V** tip, as I wasn't aware of this. I don't suppose you know if this is a default Windows feature or if it only applies to TinyMCE do you?

Comment: I know it's not a TinyMCE feature, other than that it seems to work in some programs and not in others. It works in most browsers, and many other programs (excluding most Office programs).

Comment: Ahh brilliant. Cause we've been using WP at work at lot recently (shoot me now) and I've had to dev a small form that strips all text formatting for when it gets copied into the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little additional info to @johanpw's answer

Some of you like to go a few steps further with your article as add additional things (such as a table) that do not appear to be an option with the default TinyMCE Editor.

There **are** more options that come with TinyMCE which you must activate first before being able to use them;

## Step 1:

Go to **Extensions** (top menu) >> **Plugin Manager** >> **TinyMCE**

---

## Step 2:

Set the value of the **Functionality** paramater to **Extended** (as shown below)

[image]

---

## Result:

[image]

Comment: Important information, +1 for pointing it out.